# regular expression to extract "5 rnd" from "5 Rnd (5-5-5-5-5)"

Tags: python, python-re

To put it simply, from "5 Rnd (5-5-5-5-5)", I need to extract the "5 Rnd" part, where the number could be any number, and the "Rnd" is sometimes written "rnd", sometimes "RND", or sometimes just "Rnd"

Comment: I'd suggest converting your string to lower case (or use `re.IGNORECASE`) and use `\d+ rnd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`txt` - input text

```py
import re
re.findall("\d+\s*rnd", txt, re.I)
```

`\d+` 1, or more digits

`\s*` 0 or more spaces

`rnd` letters "rnd"

`re.I` case insensitive search

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where `5 Rnd` string can occur, you can either catch any occurance like this:

```
re.search(r"\d+ rnd", "5 Rnd (5-5-5-5-5)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Or you can catch it in the beginning before the parentheses

```
re.search(r"^(\d+ rnd) \(", "5 Rnd (5-5-5-5-5)", re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```